# How can I stop canvas from adding onto the rotation?

Tags: rotation, html5-canvas, rectangles

I'm trying to get a rectangle to rotate 10 degrees counterclockwise, in a game loop. I want the box to **only** rotate 10 degrees. Not add another 10 degrees on the next loop, because that's what it's doing:

- [First iteration of Game Loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohQij.png)
- [Second Iteration of Game Loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxIuj.png)

Here is my current draw function:

```js
...

class Bok {
    static width = 17;
    static height = 12;

    constructor(position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    draw() {
        ...

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(this.position.x, this.position.y, 17, 12);
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
        ctx.lineWidth = 10;

        ctx.translate(this.position.x + Bok.width / 2, this.position.y + Bok.height / 2);
        // this keeps adding 10 degrees to the box every update,
        // how can i rotate it 10 degrees without adding on to the
        // previous rotation?
        ctx.rotate(10);
        ctx.translate(-(this.position.x + Bok.width / 2), -(this.position.y + Bok.height / 2));

        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fill();

        ...
    }

...
```

Comment: Do you want to only prevent the rotation from adding up or do you also want to prevent translation et al.?

Comment: I want to only prevent the rotation from adding up, and be able to set a different rotation each update loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, looking at your code it seems you got confused on how the API works.
You need to transform the context **before** you draw (define) the path.

Now, there are many ways to not accumulate transformations:

The long way: **perform the inverse transformation.**

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const duration = 5000;
const cx = 150;
const cy = 80;
const start = performance.now();

function draw( time ) {

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  const delta = ((start - time) % duration) / duration;
  ctx.translate( cx, cy );
  ctx.rotate( Math.PI * 2 * delta );
  ctx.translate( -cx, -cy );
  ctx.strokeRect( cx - 20, cy - 40, 40, 80 ); 
  // inverse
  ctx.translate( cx, cy );
  ctx.rotate( Math.PI * 2 * delta * -1);
  ctx.translate( -cx, -cy );

  // an horizontal line
  ctx.fillRect(0, 80, canvas.width, 5);
  requestAnimationFrame( draw ); 
}
requestAnimationFrame( draw );
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

The short but slow way, save() before drawing and restore() after. But this will save and restore every properties of your canvas context, which may be an overkill.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const duration = 5000;
const cx = 150;
const cy = 80;
const start = performance.now();

function draw( time ) {

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  const delta = ((start - time) % duration) / duration;

  ctx.save();
  
  ctx.translate( cx, cy );
  ctx.rotate( Math.PI * 2 * delta );
  ctx.translate( -cx, -cy );
  ctx.strokeRect( cx - 20, cy - 40, 40, 80 ); 
  
  ctx.restore();
  
  // an horizontal line
  ctx.fillRect(0, 80, canvas.width, 5);
  requestAnimationFrame( draw ); 
}
requestAnimationFrame( draw );
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

The clean way: **reset your context transform to an identity matrix**.
This may look a bit more complicated, but when your code will grow and you'll have a lot objects to manage, having them all relative to the identity matrix will save you from a lot of troubles.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const duration = 5000;
const cx = 150;
const cy = 80;
const start = performance.now();

function draw( time ) {

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  const delta = ((start - time) % duration) / duration;
  ctx.translate( cx, cy );
  ctx.rotate( Math.PI * 2 * delta );
  ctx.translate( -cx, -cy );
  ctx.strokeRect( cx - 20, cy - 40, 40, 80 ); 

  // clear to identity transform
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0 ,0);

  // an horizontal line
  ctx.fillRect(0, 80, canvas.width, 5);
  requestAnimationFrame( draw ); 
}
requestAnimationFrame( draw );
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: I can see you worked really hard on this answer, but i don’t want the rotation to add up. I want the rotation to stay 10 degrees, while running `rotate(10)` on each frame. I don’t want the degrees to add to the previous context 

Comment: @BokTheBirb read that answer carefully, the rotation doesn't add up, it rotates at every frame because I ask it to rotate, through the angle argument of `rotate()` but the horizontal one stays still. Simply keep a constant `angle` and you're good to go.

Comment: Im making flappy bird, and I want a rectangle or image to rotate depending on the bird’s velocity, i do that without adding onto the velocity?

Comment: Yes, you define an `angle` variable based on whatever you want (mine is based on the time elapsed).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to make a trigger for it.

```
class Bok {
    static width = 17;
    static height = 12;

    constructor(position) {
        this.position = position;
        this.rotated = false;
    }

    draw() {
        ...

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(this.position.x, this.position.y, 17, 12);
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
        ctx.lineWidth = 10;

        ctx.translate(this.position.x + Bok.width / 2, this.position.y + Bok.height / 2);
       
        if (!this.rotated) {
        ctx.rotate(10);
        this.rotated = true;
        }
        ctx.translate(-(this.position.x + Bok.width / 2), -(this.position.y + Bok.height / 2));

        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fill();

        ...
    }

...
```

adding updated code to rotate based on velocity

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = innerWidth;
canvas.height = 500;

let friction = 0.8;
let gravity = 1.5;

class Player {
  constructor() {
    this.x = 128;
    this.y = 260;
    this.w = 32;
    this.h = 32;
    this.vx = 0;
    this.vy = 0;
    this.speed = 3;
    this.color = "green";
    this.a = 0;
    this.r = this.a * (Math.PI/180);
  }
  draw() {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.translate(this.x+this.w/2, this.y+this.h/2)
    ctx.rotate(-this.r);
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.w, this.h);
    ctx.restore();
  }
  update() {
    if (controller.space) {
      this.vy < 10 ? this.vy -= this.speed : this.vy = 10;
      this.a < 10 ? this.a += 0.5 : this.a = 10;
    } else {
      this.a > 0 ? this.a -= 0.5 : this.a = 0;
    }
    this.r = this.a * (Math.PI/180);
    this.vy += gravity;
    this.y += this.vy;
    this.vy *= friction;
    this.draw()
  }
  canvasCollision() {
    if (this.x <= 0) this.x = 0;
    if (this.y <= 0) this.y = 0;
    if (this.x + this.w >= canvas.width) this.x = canvas.width - this.w;
    if (this.y + this.h >= canvas.height) {
      this.y = canvas.height - this.h;
      this.vy = 0;
    }
  }
}
let player = new Player();

function handlePlayer() {
  player.draw();
  player.update();
}

class Controller {
  constructor() {
    this.space = false;

    let keyPress = (e) => {
      if (e.code === "Space") this.space = e.type === "keydown";
    };

    window.addEventListener("keydown", keyPress);
    window.addEventListener("keyup", keyPress);
  }
}
let controller = new Controller();

function animate() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.font = 'bold 48px serif';
  ctx.fillText("Spacebar", 100, 50);
  player.update();
  player.canvasCollision();
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
animate();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: hm... so there is no way to rotate the rectangle without rotating the entire context?

Comment: You can rotate objects with rotating the context. I am still unsure what exactly your end goal is though. You mentioned flappy bird above. So is the goal to hit the spacebar and when the bird accelerates up it rotates slightly?

Comment: I added a snippet. You'll want to make it full screen. Please provide more clarity on exactly what you want also.